Allow user to access root ftp directory
I have the following situation: I have a sensor that has data streaming capability over FTP, however it is not possible to specify which folder to use to save the data.
After I input the FTP server IP, user, and password, it directly tries to save data under the root directory. If I make the root directory writeable (+write access), connection request raises 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot() error.
I tried adding allow_writeable_chroot=YES to my /etc/vsftpd.conf, however it does not change anything. Hopefully, this will be one off thing, I will use for a few hours and never visit back again.
Thank you!
Do you have any idea?
disclaimer: I read from many threads that giving root access is not a good method. Nonetheless, I have no other solutions.

Set local_root in /etc/vsftpd.conf For good measure restart the service.
